# Serial data sniffer not working as expected

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, rs485

I'm trying to get serial data from one port `/dev/ttyUSB0` and pass it to the second one `/dev/ttyUSB1` and vice versa. By my, apparently, flaunted logic the code below should work as expected. But the data seems not to reach the second port correctly, as I am not getting a correct response. I need my own program because I need to control the flow of data between the two serial devices.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    /* setup for non-canonical mode */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* fetch bytes as they become available */
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void set_mincount(int fd, int mcount)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = mcount ? 1 : 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;        /* half second timer */

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) < 0)
        printf("Error tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

void read_send(int port1, int port2) 
{
    unsigned char buf[1024];
    int rdlen;
    int wlen;
    printf("Reading port 1\n"); 
    rdlen = read(port1, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
    if (rdlen > 0) {
        unsigned char *p;
        printf("Writing %d:\n", rdlen);
        wlen = write (port2, buf, rdlen);
        tcdrain(port2);
        if (wlen != rdlen) {
            printf("Error from write: %d, %s\n", wlen, strerror(errno));
        }

    } else if (rdlen < 0) {
        printf("Error from read: %d: %s\n", rdlen, strerror(errno));
    }

}
void connect_data(int port1, int port2)
{
    //read 1 write on 2; read 2 write on 1
    read_send(port1, port2);
    read_send(port2, port1);
}

int main()
{
    char *portname_cp = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    char *portname_rfid = "/dev/ttyUSB1";
    int fd_cp;
    int fd_rfid;
    int wlen;

    fd_rfid = open(portname_rfid, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    fd_cp = open(portname_cp, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd_rfid < 0) {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", portname_rfid, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (fd_cp < 0) {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", portname_cp, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Ports opened\n");
    /*baudrate 115200, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    set_interface_attribs(fd_rfid, B115200);
    //set_mincount(fd_rfid, 0);                /* set to pure timed read */
    set_interface_attribs(fd_cp, B115200);
    //set_mincount(fd_cp, 0);                /* set to pure timed read */
    do {
        connect_data(fd_cp, fd_rfid);
    } while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to assume, that both ends are always sending data intermittently. You also seem to assume, that your read() always returns the whole data that one end wanted to send before waiting for the other end to respond. Both of these assumptions may be (and probably are) wrong. You should use non-blocking reads or poll/select to always expect data from both ends.

Comment: Are you sure there is any RS-485 related stuff involved here? And could you please decide which language to use? Is it C or C++?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the terminal initialization, since you copied that code (without any acknowledgement).  But as @ErkiA mentions, your **connect_data()** procedure doesn't work the way you probably expect it to.  You need separate threads for each direction, or else monitor for available input before issuing a blocking **read()**.